# How to process the script within a loop using python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to execute the script under a for loop, In last want to append back and concat to dataframe using python. script inside the loop is being executed but in last it gives the Error.

When i use the below script it gives the Error :

```
df = df.apply(test, axis=1)

Error: AttributeError: '2021-01-19' is not a valid function for 'Series' object
```

Using another line gives the Error:

```
df = df.apply(row, inplace=True)

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

**Full Code:**

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')

df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible'] 
df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 'Not feasible'].copy()

for index, file in df..iterrows():
   # Run your cleaning codes   
   try:
      file['Joining_Date'][index] = pd.to_datetime(file['Joining_Date'], errors='coerce')
      file['Joining_Date'][index] = file['Joining_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   except ValueError:
      file['status'] = ValueError
   try:
      file['age'][index] = file['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
   except ValueError:
      file['status'] = ValueError

   try:
      file[['col4','col5']][index] = file[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
   except ValueError:
      file['status'] = ValueError

   try:
      file['Contact'][index] = file['Contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
   except ValueError:
      file['status'] = ValueError

   file['flag'][index] = "feasible"

##Appending the values to dataframe and concat with the Non Executed data

df = df.apply(file, axis=1)

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index()
```

Please suggest. How to execute the data under a loop and combine with the not processed data before writing back to Excel.

Comment: Why are there two `..` in `df..iterrows`?

Comment: What is the task of `df = df.apply(file, axis=1)`? `file` needs to be a function (See [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)).

Comment: Please ignore the same, by mistake . . has been written.

Comment: @Manz You can still edit it.

Comment: @ConfusedLearner - How i can use the inside the function.

Comment: @Manz Please, post what your result is and what is expected.

Comment: @ConfusedLearner -  When using this line "df = df.apply(test, axis=1)" getting the Error - Error: AttributeError: '2021-01-19' is not a valid function for 'Series' object.

Comment: @Manz The error explains that `apply()` cannot work with some string or dictionary (like `file`), but instead takes a valid function as an argument.

Comment: @ConfusedLearner - How it can be resolved, Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
file['Joining_Date'][index] = ...
```

or

```
file['Contact'][index] = file['Contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

you have to use your `index` variable to change your dataframe by index, because currently you are not changing the dataframe, but the temporary `file` variable.

Use

```
df['column_name'].iloc[index] = ...
```

So instead of `file['Joining_Date'][index] = ...` you change the dataframe

```
df['Joining_Date'].iloc[index] = pd.to_datetime(file['Joining_Date'], errors='coerce')
```

After that just remove `apply()` and keep the last line.

I recommend reading the [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html) for pandas.